# How can I create a file in a sub-directory in Emacs Dired?

Tags: emacs, dired

I use dired to browse a directory and its sub-directories with `i` (`dired-maybe-insert-subdir`)

When the cursor is in a sub-directory, and I do `C-x C-f`, the default directory is the root of my buffer, is there a way to change that?

So if I visit /foo/bar and then I insert in bar's buffer the content of /foo/bar/baz and have my cursor there, get a mini-buffer with `/foo/bar/baz/` when I ask to visit a file (with the default keybinding or another, that doesn't matter to me).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is my own solution.

```
(defun dired-subdir-aware (orig-fun &rest args)
  (if (eq major-mode 'dired-mode)
      (let ((default-directory (dired-current-directory)))
        (apply orig-fun args))
    (apply orig-fun args)))

(advice-add 'find-file-read-args :around 'dired-subdir-aware)
```

I just learned how to use the advice function to augment existing functions (and macros).  See [(elisp) Advising Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html).

Now if you go to a subdir under dired and run `C-x C-f`, you will be prompted with a correct path.

**Update**:

Recently, I began to play with [(ido) Top](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/ido.html).  With `dired-subdir-aware` defined, I easily extend `ido-find-file` to recognize subdir with the following code.

```
(dolist (fun '(find-file-read-args ido-expand-directory))
  (advice-add fun :around 'dired-subdir-aware))
```

Comment: I didn't know about advising! That is *exactly* what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

No, **`default-directory`** is local to a buffer, not just part of a buffer.  This is by design, and there is no way to change it.

But you could of course define a command that picks up the subdir directory and then binds `default-directory` to that while it reads a file name to visit, etc.).

For example, this command will read a file name with the default directory being what you want, and then visit that file:

```
(defun foo (file)
  "..."
  (interactive
   (let ((default-directory  (dired-current-directory)))
     (list (read-file-name "File: "))))
  (find-file file))
```

And, out of the box, you can certainly visit the subdir in another Dired buffer, where `default-directory` is what you want. Commands such as `dired-do-find-marked-files` (**`F`**) and `dired-display-file` (**`C-o`**) do that.

But why do you want `default-directory` to reflect the subdir whose listing you are in? What's your use case?

Comment: `dired-current-directory` was exactly what I needed, thanks! But why does your function basically discard the result of `read-file-name`?

Comment: Huh? It does not discard it. That result becomes the value of argument `FILE`, which is passed to `find-file`. Your version (below) does nothing more, and it does something less: Your version cannot also be used *non*-interactively. I think you need to read up on [`interactive`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html).

Comment: Ha, yes, I didn't get how the `let` was an argument of `interactive`. I've rarely seen that way of using it.

Answer (score 0):

I refined [Drew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40938760/400277) to a function that does exactly what I wanted:

```
(defun dired-find-file ()
  "Find a file in the current dired directory"
  (interactive)
  (let ((default-directory (dired-current-directory)))
    (find-file (read-file-name "Find file:"))))
```

I then bound this function to a convenient key combination:

```
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook
   (lambda ()
     (local-set-key (kbd "C-x M-f") 'dired-find-file)))
```

Comment: I should downote my own answer. :-)